# Как сделать списки в ExpandableListView уже открытыми?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, expandablelistview

Или, может, какой метод перегрузить? Не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что нема такого метода в стандартной реализации, так что придётся делать руками как-то так:

```
ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.elv_main);
elv.setAdapter(adapter);
for(int i=0; i < adapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
    elv.expandGroup(i);
```

Comment: expandGroup не работает. Я писал свой адаптер, который наследуется от BaseExpandableLiseView, такого метода не перегружал(

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev, А если цикл в postDelayed выполнить?

Comment: А зачем? Если я проверку на открытие группы добавил в самом конце, после заполнения всех групп и подгрупп.

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev, ну, это реально может помочь, т.к. адаптер может быть ещё не до конца инициализирован асинхронно и проигнорировать этот код. Попробовать ведь несложно)

Comment: @AndrewDmitriev метод `expand()` - это метод виджета `ExpandableListView`, а не метод адаптера для него. Никакого класса `BaseExpandableListView` нет, есть класс адаптера `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

Comment: @pavlofff я имел ввиду BaseExpandableListAdapter, странно, что вы не увидели здесь опечатку

Comment: Спасибо, добавление в postDelayed и правда помогло!)